# How to get my pointer back in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3b+, mouse

I've used my raspberry pi for a kiosk project. My partner get rid the mouse pointer for better interface convenience.

Now, I want my pointer back because I want to do another project.

What should I do?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11 shows many ways to hide the cursor.  Without knowing what was done folk will just be guessing.  Maybe you can check the answers and see if any apply to your box?  An other way would be to start with a fresh O/S image...

Comment: ask your partner